# How to redirect nginx from http to https behind an apache reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, https

I have a wordpress site running on nginx (localhost; port 8081) behind an apache 2.4 reverse proxy. Everything works ok. Now I want to redirect all http requests to https, so I have modified my default apache virtualhost like this:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
# NO SSL - OLD
#ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/
#ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8081/
# SSL - NEW
SSLProxyEngine On
RequestHeader set Front-End-Https "On"
ProxyPass / https://localhost:8081/
ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8081/
```

And my nginx configuration like this:

```
server {
    listen 8081 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    root /home/mywordpress;
    index index.php;

    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
}
```

And added this default SSL - apache virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

    # SSL
    SSLProxyEngine On
    RequestHeader set Front-End-Https "On"
    ProxyPass / https://localhost:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8081/

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Lets encrypt is working fine. Now, when I go to http version I am redirected to https version, but ... I can see text, links and entries but not static content as javascript, css or images (404 error). That static content is still accesible. If I write its no-https url on a browser I can get it (200 OK), so something isn't working with SSL and that kind of content. I have looked for information about similar issues but I haven't found any answers. What am I doing wrong?. I am getting crazy. Thanks.

Comment: All your links probably contain the full url, including http, and you cant load insecure content over a secure connection

Comment: No, source code shows that css links are loaded through https. By example, `https://example.com/some.css` but web server dont find them (Not Found - error 404) but if I go to `http://example.com/some.css` I can see css file.

Comment: Is the problem with these kinds of file only? `js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico` What if you get rid of the caching directive for those file fypes, or purge all your caches?

Comment: No. I made a mistake, sorry. Https is not working at all. I can see text, links, etc ... but is under http, I can't see css and js because wordpress must be rewriting paths to use https and as https is not working only text is being showed. This approach must be wrong.

Comment: I have tried editing default virtualhost to:  `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` with no proxy directives but now I only get a page with de typical directory index.

Comment: **[SOLVED]**. The idea is redirect Apache 80 to Apache:443 and configure Apache's 443 virtualhost to proxy to nginx, but I needed to change rewrite rule above to this `Redirect permanent / https://example.com`, then I edited https virtualhost from `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` to `<VirtualHost example.com:443>` and **restarted** all services: `sudo service apache2 restart && sudo service nginx restart`. If I tried to reload instead of restart I got an error. Miknik, thanks for your responses.